# How to call and iterate values from a yaml file parsed using python?

Tags: python, iterator, duplicates, nameerror

1. I have a yaml file as below:

   ```
   server1:
     host: os1
     ip: ##.###.#.##
     path: /var/log/syslog
     file: syslog
     identityfile: /identityfile/keypair.pub

   server2:
     host: os2
     ip: ##.###.#.##
     path: /var/log/syslog
     file: syslog.1
     identityfile: /identityfile/id_rsa.pub
   ```

I have a piece of code to parse the yaml and read entries.

## read data from the config yaml file

```
    def read_yaml(file):
        with open(file, "r") as stream:
    try:
        config = yaml.load(stream)
        print(config)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
        print("\n")
return config
```

read_yaml("config_file")
print(config)

My problems:
1. I am unable to return values and I get a "NameError: name 'config' is not defined" at the print statement called outside the function.

2. How can I iterate and read the values in my yaml file by passing only the parameters?
   Ex: 
       print('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**config['os1']))
   but without the 'os1' as the yaml file may have 100s of entries
3. I ensured there are no duplicates by using sets but want to use a loop and store the values from my string formatting command into a variable without using 'os1' or 'os2' or 'os#'.

   ```
   def iterate_yaml():
   remotesys = set()

   for key,val in config.items():
       print("{} = {}".format(key,val))


   #check to ensure duplicates are removed by storing it in a set

   remotesys.add('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**config['os1']))
   remotesys.add('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**config['os2']))
   remotesys.add('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**config['os3']))
   ```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get the `NameError` exception because you don't return any values. You have to return `config` from the function.

For example:

```
def read_yaml(...):
    # code

     return config
```

Then, by calling `read_yaml`, you'll get your configuration returned.

Check the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org) & tutorials for that.

2-3. You can perform a `for` loop using the `dict.items` method.

For example:

```
x = {'lol': 1, 'kek': 2}

for name, value in x.items():
    print(name, value)
```

Comment: thank you. Suppose I have x,y,z,a,b,c..etc then do you have an idea how to handle this case?